# Issues getting running

Tags: jhipster

I've had a couple of issues with the generated app.  I haven't gotten into it yet, but I commented out he @EnableScheduling and it runs.  Seems like a spring issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V
at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$180fc4ed.setBeanFactory(<generated>)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$EnhancedConfigurationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:442)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
... 65 more
```

Next the application config files had wrong classes in them:  The .conf. was causing an issue.  Should have been .config.

```
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.mycompany.hipster.conf.hazelcast.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
```

Instead of

```
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.mycompany.hipster.config.hazelcast.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
```

Lastly the DB information isn't setup properly at least for Postgres.  The URL and username were missing.  If you could update the installation doc to cover that or just have it default to localhost.  Maybe spit out the config information when running in dev.

One other thing is the warning from hibernate:

```
[WARN] org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
```

Very cool setup.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug!

- I created an issue to reference it: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/106
- And I did a new release which corrects it: http://jhipster.github.io/2014/01/23/jhipster-release-0.8.2.html

Comment: I'm really digging the framework you put together.  I was just working on a archetype this morning like this and then ran across this on yeoman.  Thank you again!